# serving javascript with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this code down here. When format.js fires I want to serve to the client a javascript file. How do I do that?

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController

def destroy
  @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
  @line_item.destroy

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to line_items_url }
    format.js {}
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

I have a file called destroy.js.erb in the controller, but that doesn't run automatically. I   tried many combinations but nothing seems to work...

what do I put inside format.js { ??? } to serve a javascript file I want? I don't want to write vanilla javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To trigger your js-response of your destroy action try:

```
<%= button_to 'Remove', @line_item, method: :delete, remote: :true %>
```

For testing purpose make your `destroy.js.erb` as the following:

```
alert("Line item with id <%= @line_item.id %> has been removed");
```

You can leave your `format.js` w/o bracket (or with empty ones).